# In-HTML iteration error with Jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm messing around with federated log in for an app that I'm working on.  The code worked already in a less beautiful way, but when I tried to pretty things up by instead doing in-html iteration rather than iteration then html I've been getting this error.

```
  File "/home/wes/PycharmProjects/Unit3/templates/login.html", line 26, in top-level    template code
{% for p in new_providers.keys() %}
 UndefinedError: 'new_providers' is undefined
```

This is the code (providers is a separate key: value dict)

```
new_providers = {}
for name in providers.keys():
    new_providers[name] = users.create_login_url(federated_identity=providers[name])


else:
     error = "You are not logged in"
     self.render("login.html", error=error, new_providers = new_providers)
```

And Finally, here is the HTML and Jinja to render the dictionary.  This is what I suspect something is wrong with but nothing seems obvious to me...

```
{% for p in new_providers.keys() %}
        <a href="{{ new_providers[p] }}">{{ p }}</a>
        <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The normal dict loop, looks like : {% for key, value in new_providers %}

Comment: How are you defining your `render` function?

Comment: render is built-in to jinja2

Comment: template = env.get_template('mytemplate.html')
To render it with some variables, just call the render() method:

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I don't know why this was the case exactly but here was the change that fixed the issue (the change is in IF condition's self.render

Original code:

```
class Login(Handler):
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        username = user.nickname()
        log_out = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        self.write(users.create_login_url(federated_identity='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'))

        self.render("login.html", log_out=log_out, username=username)
    else:
        error = "You are not logged in"
        self.render("login.html", error=error, new_providers=new_providers)
```

Amended Code

```
class Login(Handler):
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        username = user.nickname()
        log_out = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        self.write(users.create_login_url(federated_identity='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'))

        self.render("login.html", log_out=log_out, username=username, **new_providers=new_providers**)
    else:
        error = "You are not logged in"
        self.render("login.html", error=error, new_providers = new_providers)
```

Comment: After doing this I realized I should have posted this code instead of what I did in the question because you guys probably would have noticed right away, so I apologize for that.